# Is it possible to make the height of an element 100% of it's container width?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to make an element have the same width and height so it is a perfect square. However the width is not a set value but rather defined by the viewport plus some whitespace. The whitespace is defined by some `grid` `fr` units plus some margins and paddings outside the dsired element and it's parent. So I have not found an easy way to calculate something like `--size: 100vw - **whitespace**`. I'd like to achieve this by using only CSS if possible.

Here's a working example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.example {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.example > div {
    background-color: teal;
    border: 4px solid blue;
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
}
.taller {
    flex-basis: 40%;
    height: 500px;
}
.shorter {
    flex-basis: 60%;
    height: 250px;
}
.perfectCircle {
    border: 4px solid red;
    --size: 100%;
    width: var(--size);
    height: var(--size);
    border-radius: 50%;

    position: relative;
}
.perfectCircle > p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
p {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
    <p>The width of the teal containers should define the size of the perfect <del>square</del> circle inside</p>
    <div class="taller">
        <div class="perfectCircle">
            <p>
                This should ALWAYS be a perfect <del>square</del> circle and leave whitespace on top or bottom if needed.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shorter">
        <div class="perfectCircle">
            <p>
                This should ALWAYS be a perfect <del>square</del> circle and overflow the container if needed.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post CSS and HTML as a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a CSS property just for that: [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio)

> The aspect-ratio CSS property sets a preferred aspect ratio for the
> box, which will be used in the calculation of auto sizes and some
> other layout functions.

**Not compatible with Internet Explorer**

```css
article {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 1em 30%;
  padding: 0;
  background: lime;
}

section {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 10%;
  background: brown;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <section>
    <div></div>
  </section>
</article>
```

Comment: OMG I can't believe I never found about the "aspect-ratio" property while searching for a solution. Thanks a lot this is it.